# Convert xml to stored procudure type of datatable

Tags: c#

I am getting a datatable from a stored procedure from my db and then converting to xml and storing in a settings file.

```
dsTableAdapters.usp_GetMyDataTableAdapter taMyData = new dsTableAdapters.usp_GetMyDataTableAdapter();
ds.usp_GetMyDataDataTable dtMyData  = taMyData.GetData();

string xmlMyData;
using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
{
    dtMyData.WriteXml(sw);
    xmlMyData = sw.ToString();
}
```

This works fine.

Seperately (if the user is not online) I want to read the settings file and use this instead. I can get the data into a standard datatable by

```
StringReader theReader = new StringReader(xmlMyData);
DataSet theDataSet = new DataSet();
theDataSet.ReadXml(theReader);
DataTable mydt = theDataSet.Tables[0];
```

but my problem is a cannot cast this into a ds.usp_GetMyDataDataTable type datatable. Doing

```
dtMyData = (ds.usp_GetMyDataDataTable)mydt;
```

doesn't work. Any ideas welcome.

Comment: because they aren't the same at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating Lists of types instead of passing around a procedure specific result set object.  What you are experiences is why you create Entities or Domain object to store data that can be populated from various sources.

Anyway there is no obvious quick answer to your question, your question is basically asking why doesn't a `DataTable` cast to a Custom Class that you've created and the reason is because they are 2 completely different classes.

Comment: I understand why it wont let me cast a datatable to a custom class but given i can go from a custom class to an xml as I have shown above, surely there must be a way to go from the xml to my cusom class?

Comment: that's because an xml object is just a list of nodes of names and values that is an entirely different operation than implicitly casting an object to a different type.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it working in the end. Putting the answer here in case anyone else is interested although you may want to take on T McKeown's advice that I shouldn't be doing it this way

```
dtMyData = new ds.usp_GetMyDataDataTable();
StringReader theReader = new StringReader(Properties.Settings.Default.MyData);
dtMyData.ReadXml(theReader);
```